# import Spark source code into intellij, build Error: not found: type SparkFlumeProtocol and EventBatch

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors, apache-spark

**IntelliJ**: 14.1.4

**Spark**: 1.5 release source code

I'm importing Spark source code into IntelliJ, and following steps on [Spark website](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-IntelliJ).

I'm getting errors below when building and compiling the project. I've googled around and tried what is [suggested here in spark user list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/A-Spark-Compilation-Question-td8402.html) to "Generate Sources and Update Folders" in Maven tool bar for "Spark Project External Flume Sink", but still with same errors.

I'm pretty sure it's a resolve issue since all other classes are successfully resolved. Maybe I'm not using IntelliJ correctly? Any suggestions please?

```
Error:(45, 66) not found: type SparkFlumeProtocol
  val transactionTimeout: Int, val backOffInterval: Int) extends SparkFlumeProtocol with Logging {
                                                                 ^
Error:(70, 39) not found: type EventBatch
  override def getEventBatch(n: Int): EventBatch = {
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved the problem, and it turns out that the "Spark Project External Flume Sink" is **excluded** when importing Spark source code under default settings.

What I did:

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> "spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10" -> Sources
2. in the tree display of folders, initially **"target" folder is excluded, but the "SparkFlumeProtocol" and "EventBatch" classes are compiled into this folder**.
3. set "target" folder as "Sources", then leave all under "target" as "Excluded" except for "scala-2.10", see attached screenshot.

In this way, the compiles classes are included and the classes can be resolved correctly after a re-build project.

[image]

--- update June-8-2016 --------

or more specifically, the whole path of this module

**please note the type and color, it will affect the package name**

```
package org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink;
```

[image]

Comment: Note: I had to run `sbt avro:generate` before 'src_managed' appeared in the tree, per the advice [here](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Intellij-Spark-Source-Compilation-tp12168p12196.html)